# avoid Javascript variable modification from browser console

Tags: javascript, security, variables, global

I have a problem. I have defined some global variables and namespaced it into an object called "app".
Example:

```
window.app : {
    foo : null,
    bar : null,
}
```

Well, the idea is that I want to be able to modify those variables from any module by calling app.foo = "baz" or app.bar = "baz", but I don't want the user to be able to modify those variables from the browser console (element inspector).

Is it possible?

PD: Well, I have a Backbone.js collection which is sinchronized with the server. I don't want the user to be able to modify that collection with the console

Comment: No, it's not. The user of the browser can always do anything they want.

Comment: Is there another way to do it? I need to protect those variables from console modification, but also I need it to be modifiable from the written code

Comment: What is so important about these variables that they shouldn't be changeD?

Comment: And why would you want to restrict that really? You should rather embrace users experimenting.

Comment: @edwardoyarzun keep in mind that you really have no way of knowing that your user is actually using what we'd call a "web browser" at all.

Comment: Well, I have a Backbone.js collection which is sinchronized with the server. I don't want the user to be able to modify that collection with the console

Comment: Changing the var from the console can be prevented by using const modifier for your variables. Please check my answer at the bottom for details.

Answer (score 9):

No. The browser is the user's domain. They have the possibility to modify your scripts and inject their own functionality in various ways (through the console or browser plug-ins). That's one of the reasons why you should never blindly trust user input on the server side.

They could even manually forge a complete request, tricking your server into thinking that your JavaScript code made that request.

If you want these values to be secure, you need to keep them on the server. You can send them to the client, of course, as long as you keep a possibility to validate the values against those on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make the variables not (easily) modifiable by a user is to remove them from global scope - something like

```
!function() {
  foo = null;
  bar = null;
}()
```

You'll need to redesign the way your modules interact with each other to accomplish this. An MVC Framework like Angular.js will help.

You should never rely on this as a security mechanism, though - the browser is fully in the user's control.

Comment: Is there a way to access `foo` from the Chrome console now? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Still for them who are searching solution to this problem, use **const** modifier while assigning variable instead of **var**. Now try to change value of variable from browser console. It will throw error *Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable* that will prevent your data from being modified.

Comment: I'm making a game, and I want to implement this with a `points` variable. Now I can't use a constant because the points change as they score, but I don't want them to set their points to `1000`. What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to avoid to (easily) modify javascript variables from the browser console is to either use the [get operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get) (ECMAScript 5) or a getter-function.

To make it possible to define "private" variables, an anonymous function defines the variables in the local scope, so that it is not globally available. (as mentioned in joews' answer)

As mentioned before, this does not make it impossible to manipulate the variables.

Via get operator:

```
window.app = (function () {
    var _foo = 123; // private variable
    return {
        get foo () { return _foo; }
    };
}());

// --- accessing app from the console ---
// app.foo is readable from console, but not modifiable
console.log(app.foo);
app.foo = 234;
console.log(app.foo); // 123
// However, app.foo can still be modified via Object.defineProperty or
// removed with the delete operator
```

Via getter-function (older browsers, e.g IE < 9):

```
window.app = (function () {
    var _foo = 123; // private variable
    return {
        foo: function() { return _foo; }
    };
}());

// --- accessing app from the console ---
console.log(app.foo()); // 123
// However, the foo function can still be overwritten.
// But at least, the internal _foo variable is unaffected.
app.foo = function () { return 234; }
```