# How to secure global scope variables and prevent users from accessing it via console

Tags: javascript

I have some special variables declared in the global scope. Now am a bit concern because the data am storing in these variable are the heart of the application am working on.

Upon trying to access it via console I found it was very easy and that is not fully secured.

How do I make it hard to access it and secure these variables still in the global scope ?

code:

```
`//declare special variables global scope and use it throughout the application when needed

var recipientsInfo          = [],
    recipients              = [],
    buddyList               = [],
    webMessengerDataAr      = [],
    __ActiveConlog_data     = [],
    activeConArray          = [];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Store them inside function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avoid Javascript variable modification from browser console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262902/avoid-javascript-variable-modification-from-browser-console)

Comment: You can't prevent access if they are in global scope, they need to be in a closure

Comment: It must be said that this will *not* make your code more secure.

Comment: Users can use a debugger to access and modify your variables. You can't prevent it.

Comment: @Oriol Yep, was just about to post this. If the browser has a debugger, the user can put a breakpoint in any scope and inspect (and change) whatever they want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple: if you have variables within your code and you want to store them safely, you have to basically drop them into self invoking anonymous function which will work like a closure.

```
(function() {
    // just drag your whole code from your script.js and drop it here
})();
```

Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: It's quite simple indeed!. So in this case it declares anonymous function which then calls  itself immediately. good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to bundled your code inside IIFE

```
(function() {
    // your variable goes here
})();
```

then your variable are no longer in global scope, it's create new scope.

if you don't know what IIFE is take a look at this page [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).
Also a useful pattern for avoiding global scope based on IIFE called [module pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) might help you.

Comment: ups, sorry i didn't read the solution that you wanted is still in global scope

Comment: I found this on a website ...but I don't know how to use the variables in another functions...Can you help on that??